# Xcode flex lexer not generated

Tags: xcode, dependencies, lex, flex-lexer

I'm having an issue with xcode. My project has a lexer which should be created (from lexer.l) before compiling anything. Flex should create two files from lexer.l: lexer.c and lexer.h. The latter is included in some other files. What happens now is Xcode does not process lexer.l and then complains about missing lexer.h. lexer.l is include in the compile sources list under build phases. Any thoughts?

Comment: You'll need to create a custom build rule for it.  I have done it in my project, but I'm not at home at the moment...

Comment: I removed the "Adobe Flex" Tag and tagged this as Lex and gnu-flex; as I believe those are more apt for what you're after.

Comment: @trojanfoe I thought Xcode would be smart enough to do this on its own since there is a build rule for lexers

Comment: @Patrik I found I had to create my own, but this was before I embedded flex options into the lexer file itself. I have since started generating mine using a perl script which post-processes the generated `.cpp` file, so you might be right.

Comment: mmm, it looks like it fixed itself after re-creating the project but the default rule is not right for me. Can I write a rule similar to what I use in make? 
$(LEX) --prefix=$(basename $(@F)) --header-file=include/$(basename $(@F)).h -o $@ $^

Comment: Mind those tags! This can't possibly be a `flex` problem, since the issue is that `flex` is never executed!

Answer (score 1):

One year late I can provide a solution. Maybe someone else can use it.
As I read on some answer on SO Xcode needs some special file extensions to map them to the different programming languages. When you want to compile c++ code f.e. you have to give the lexfile the ending .lpp. Xcode will handle the rest

Comment: Man, I've been look everywhere for this answer. Best solution, by far!